# PHP artisan command one argument with spaces in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, command, laravel-artisan

I am just trying to make php artisan command like this.

`php artisan user:comments ID Comments`

Here ID is number and comments are a number of comments separated by **spaces**.
So the real command example:

`php artisan user:comments 1 comment1 comment2 comment3 ...`

I made the command by using `php artisan make:command` and defined signature `protected $signature = 'user:comments {id?} {comments?}';`.

It works if arguments are matches the params but getting one arguement contains spaces doesn't work since command notices space is a separation of argument.
I get this error:
[image]

Now I want to make the comment argument as one contains all comments.
So if I input `php artisan user:comments 1 comment1 comment2`, I want to get 2 arguments `$this->argument('id')` and `$this->argument('comments')` where I can get all comments by handling string operation like splitting spaces.

If I use the comments with comma not spaces, it works. But I want space separation.
[image]

Does anybody have a similar experience to this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @kerbh0lz please don't just post links. This link might be deleted in the future and the possible solution is gone.

Comment: @Florian Links only are ok in comments imho. In an answer though I'm with you

Comment: I think the link is helpful and works for input arguments with spaces! Thank you @kerbh0lz, btw one more thing. How should I set it's optional and array concurrently?
`{comments*?}` is possible?

Comment: No clue, sorry, need to try it out

Comment: Thank you, I found it . The correct syntax for array optional input is `{comments?*} ` :) It worked well!

Answer (score 1):

The argument should be enclosed in quotes.

```
php artisan user:comments 1 'comment1 comment2 comment3'

protected $signature = 'user:comments {id?} {comments?}';
```